# How to make a union query of two different entities in Slick?

Tags: slick, slick-3.0

I want to make a query that combines the list of two different entities into a single list.

My plan was to use Options:

```
// +------+---------+---------+
// | size | Some(a) | None    |
// | size | None    | Some(b) |
// +------+---------+---------+

val queryA = TableQuery[TableA].map { a => 
  (a.size, Rep.Some(a), Rep.None[TableB]) 
}

val queryB = TableQuery[TableB].map { b => 
  (b.size, Rep.None[TableA], Rep.Some(b)) 
}

val union = (queryA ++ queryB)
```

However, it does not work. `Rep.None` does not support multi-column values and the compiler misses `TypedType[TableA]` and `TypedType[TableB]`.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating the union of the id columns only first then joining the tables. Far from optimal but works. Still looking for a better solution.

```
// +------+------------+------------+
// | size | Some(a.id) | None       |
// | size | None       | Some(b.id) |
// +------+------------+------------+

val queryIdA = TableQuery[TableA].map { a => 
  (a.size, Rep.Some(a.id), Rep.None[TableB]) 
}

val queryIdB = TableQuery[TableB].map { b => 
  (b.size, Rep.None[TableA], Rep.Some(b.id)) 
}

val union = (queryIdA ++ queryIdB).sortBy { case (size, _, _) => size.desc }
  .joinLeft(TableQuery[TableA]).on { case ((_, aid, _), a) => aid.nonEmpty && aid === a.id }
  .joinLeft(TableQuery[TableB]).on { case (((_, _, bid), _), b) => bid.nonEmpty && bid === b.id }
  .map { case (((_, _, _), a), b) => (a, b) }
```